# How to control RX/TX size for a BLE connection in a C# program running on Windows?

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, mtu

I am connecting to a BLE device from a C# program using the [`Windows.Devices.Bluetooth` WinRT API](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth).

The code uses an [`BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher) for scanning to verify the device is in range, then uses the [`BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice.frombluetoothaddressasync) method to connect.

The peripheral is an STM32WB55, which then tries to negotiate a bigger MTU using the `hci_le_set_data_length` function to request MTU 251 and transmission time 2120ms in TX direction (as seen from the peripheral, so peripheral->central), and `aci_l2cap_connection_parameter_update_req` to request a connection interval of 48.75ms, and a timeout of 5000ms.

For any central, there's not much to *send to* the peripheral, but a lot of data to *receive from* it. So splitting a connection event with asymmetric phase durations is very beneficial. And in fact, on Android with "nRF Connect" as the connecting app, I can see that once all negotiation has finished, the connection configuration settled on (as seen from the peripheral) is:

> **nRF Connect**
>
> - Interval: 48.75ms
> - Latency: 0
> - Timeout: 5000ms
> - TX Size: 251
> - TX Time: 2120ms
> - RX Size: 27
> - RX Time: 328ms
> - MTU: 251

So for nRF Connect, the peripheral can send a lot of data and will only wait to receive few data, which is perfect and exactly what I want. In Windows 10 and 11 however, the final configuration is reported to have ended up as follows:

> **Windows 10/11**
>
> - Interval: 48.75ms
> - Latency: 0
> - Timeout: 5000ms
> - TX Size: 123
> - TX Time: 1096ms
> - RX Size: 123
> - RX Time: 1096ms
> - MTU: 251

As you can see, Windows *does* respect the requested interval, timeout, and MTU, but it splits each connection event evenly into [TX 123, RX 123] opposed to nRF Connect's [TX 251, RX 27].

Is there anything I can do to get Windows to split the connection event unevenly, i. e. more time peripheral->central and less time central->peripheral? The API seems to lack any means of controlling that part - or am I overlooking something here?

(Side note: Starting from Windows 11, the [`BluetoothLEDevice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice) has a [`RequestPreferredConnectionParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice.requestpreferredconnectionparameters) method. Unfortunately this method only allows to change interval, latency and timeout, as evident from the effect requesting any of the static members [`PowerOptimized`](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothlepreferredconnectionparameters.poweroptimized) (180ms / 6000ms), [`Balanced`](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothlepreferredconnectionparameters.balanced) (60ms / 4000ms), or [`ThroughputOptimized`](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothlepreferredconnectionparameters.throughputoptimized) (15ms / 2000ms) has.)

Comment: On Windows 10 you can not control MTU/PDU size. On Windows 11 you can set it to any value, not only to predefined. However there is some trick and I'm not sure it can be used from UWP app. From desktop application it works fine.

Comment: You said "On Windows 11 you can set [the MTU/PDU size] to any value", but from Desktop application, maybe not UWP. How do I do it for a desktop application?

Comment: Bluetooth Framework allows to do that. Unfortunately I can not share the code. Changing Connection Parameters you can also control PDU size.